# Best way to find the largest value in a Hashmap<Arraylist,Arraylist>

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

I have a hashmap as show here;

```
HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>,ArrayList<String>>
```

I'd like to find the ArrayList with the greatest length() from the second ArrayList (the value)

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You're going to have to iterate over the entrySet of the map. If the value ArrayLists are sorted, you can just look at the last element. Otherwise you'll have to check every element one by one.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over the map's [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29):

```
ArrayList<String> max = null;

for (ArrayList<String> list : map.values()) {
    if (max == null || list.size() > max.size())
        max = list;
}
```

---

To get the key associated with the largest value:

```
ArrayList<Integer> maxKey = null;
int maxLen = 0;

for (Entry<ArrayList<Integer>, ArrayList<String>> e : map.entrySet()) {
    int len = e.getValue().size();

    if (maxKey == null || len > maxLen) {
        maxKey = e.getKey();
        maxLen = len;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the last `ArrayList` in `map.values()` is `null`, this will say that the longest one is `null`, even though something else may have an actual size. Perhaps the if statement should say `if (max != null && list.size() > max.size())`

Comment: @wlyles If one of the values is `null` then there will be an NPE when `list.size()` is called. If the OP has null values in the map (which he really shouldn't) then he can easily adapt this approach to check for that. The underlying concept, however, will remain the same.

Comment: What if we have to find the key with ArrayList with largest length?

Comment: @AKS You can use exactly the same approach, just iterate over the `keySet()` instead of the `values()`.

Comment: @arshaji, Looks like i was not clear in my question, I need hashmap key for which value is max length of array list. That means in HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>,ArrayList<String>> , if ArrayList<String> has largest length then i need corresponding ArrayList<Integer> . Now iterating over keyset will give you ArrayList<Integer> with largest legth which is not my intention here.

Comment: @arshajii, just added new comment. you can answer it now.

Answer (score 0):

Once the ArrayLists are in the HashMap you would have to enumerate them to find the one with the greatest length.  However, you could use the SortedMap interface with keys being the length of each Array List as an additional index and then just pick the last one very efficiently at any time.